# Airflow kubernetesExecutor : Worker pod terminate after creating

Tags: docker, kubernetes, airflow

When trying to run dag with `KubernetesExecutor` getting exception in worker pod terminate immediately after the start :

I have a question why scheduler sending LocalExecutor as an env variable that can be found in `pod describe result` is this the right behavior?

Please find the all required files:

1. airflow.cfg
2. worker dag describe
3. worker dag logs
4. dag file

Worker pod describe result :

```
Name:         tutorialv01printhello-50d3b9099ea64c19a51e2fb035eef8ac
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         worker01/<node-ip>
Start Time:   <date-time>
Labels:       airflow-worker=<airflow-dummy>
              airflow_version=1.10.11
              dag_id=tutorial_v01
              execution_date=
              kubernetes_executor=True
              task_id=print_hello
              try_number=1
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Failed
IP:           <Node Ip>
IPs:
  IP:  <Node Ip>
Containers:
  base:
    Container ID:  <container-id>
    Image:         <repo-name>/k8-airflow:latest
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://<repo-name>/k8-
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      airflow
      run
      tutorial_v01
      print_hello
      <date time>
      --local
      --pool
      default_pool
      -sd
      /usr/local/airflow/dags/tutorial_01.py
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Thu, 06 Aug 2020 13:20:21 +0000
      Finished:     Thu, 06 Aug 2020 13:20:22 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment Variables from:
      airflow-configmap  ConfigMap  Optional: false
    Environment:
      AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR:          LocalExecutor
      AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER:       /usr/local/airflow/dags/repo/
      AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN:  <alchemy-postgres-conn-url>
    Mounts:
      /usr/local/airflow/dags from airflow-dags (ro)
      /usr/local/airflow/logs from airflow-logs (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-sdfdfdd (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  airflow-dags:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  airflow-dags
    ReadOnly:   false
  airflow-logs:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  default-token-mnh2t:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-mnh2t
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age        From               Message
  ----    ------     ----       ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  <unknown>  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/tutorialv01printhello-50d3b9099ea64c19a51e2fb035eef8ac to worker01
  Normal  Pulling    8m4s       kubelet, worker01  Pulling image "<repo-name>/k8-airflow:latest"
  Normal  Pulled     8m1s       kubelet, worker01  Successfully pulled image "<repo-name>/k8-airflow:latest"
  Normal  Created    8m1s       kubelet, worker01  Created container base
  Normal  Started    8m1s       kubelet, worker01  Started container base
```

Worker pod logs :

```
  File "/usr/bin/airflow", line 25, in <module>
    from airflow.configuration import conf
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from airflow.utils.log.logging_mixin import LoggingMixin
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .decorators import apply_defaults as _apply_defaults
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/decorators.py", line 36, in <module>
    from airflow import settings
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 37, in <module>
    from airflow.configuration import conf, AIRFLOW_HOME, WEBSERVER_CONFIG  # NOQA F401
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 636, in <module>
    with open(TEST_CONFIG_FILE, 'w') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/airflow/unittests.cfg'
```

find airflow.cfg :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: airflow-configmap
  labels:
    env: airflow-test
data:
  airflow.cfg: |
    [core]
    dags_folder = /usr/local/airflow/dags
    base_log_folder = /usr/local/airflow/logs
    logging_level = INFO
    executor = KubernetesExecutor
    parallelism = 32
    load_examples = False
    plugins_folder = /usr/local/airflow/plugins
    sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://<username>:<pwd>@airflow-metastore:5432/airflow

    [celery]
    broker_url =
    result_backend =

    [webserver]
    base_url = http://0.0.0.0:8080
    rbac=False
    web_server_host = 0.0.0.0
    web_server_port = 8080
    dag_default_view = tree

    [kubernetes]
    namespace = default
    airflow_configmap =
    worker_service_account_name = default
    worker_container_image_pull_policy = Always
    worker_dags_folder = /usr/local/airflow/dags
    worker_container_repository = <repo-name>/k8-airflow
    worker_container_tag = latest
    delete_worker_pods = false
    env_from_configmap_ref = airflow-configmap
    git_repo = https://github.com/<repo-name>/airflow-dags
    git_branch = master
    git_sync_credentials_secret = git-credentials
    git_sync_root = /tmp/git
    git_dags_folder_mount_point = /usr/local/airflow/dags
    git_sync_container_repository = <repo-name>/git-sync
    git_sync_container_tag = latest
    git_sync_init_container_name = git-sync-clone
    dags_volume_claim = airflow-dags
    in_cluster = True
    dags_volume_subpath =
    dags_volume_mount_point =


    [kubernetes_environment_variables]
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR = KubernetesExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER = /usr/local/airflow/dags


    [admin]
    hide_sensitive_variable_fields = True
```

And Kubernetes file :

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: default
  namespace: default
  labels:
    env: airflow-test
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
    resources: ["pods"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "delete"]
  - apiGroups: ["batch", "extensions"]
    resources: ["jobs"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: default
  namespace: default
  labels:
    env: airflow-test
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default # Name of the ServiceAccount
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: Role # This must be Role or ClusterRole
  name: default # This must match the name of the Role or ClusterRole you wish to bind to
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: airflow
  namespace: default
  labels:
    env: airflow-test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      env: airflow-test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        env: airflow-test
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: "init"
          image: <repo-name>/k8-airflow
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          volumeMounts:
            - name: airflow-configmap
              mountPath: /usr/local/airflow/airflow.cfg
              subPath: airflow.cfg
            - name: airflow-dags
              mountPath: /usr/local/airflow/dags
          env:
            - name: SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: airflow-secrets
                  key: sql_alchemy_conn
          command:
            - "bash"
          args:
            - "-cx"
            - "initdb.sh"

      containers:
        - name: webserver
          image: <repo-name>/k8-airflow
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: NODE
              value: "webserver"
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: airflow-configmap
          ports:
            - name: webserver
              protocol: TCP
              containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/local/airflow/dags
              name: airflow-dags
            - mountPath: /usr/local/airflow/airflow.cfg
              name: airflow-configmap
              subPath: airflow.cfg
            - name: airflow-logs
              mountPath: /usr/local/airflow/logs
        - name: scheduler
          image: <repo-name>/k8-airflow
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: NODE
              value: "scheduler"
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: airflow-configmap
          ports:
            - name: webserver
              protocol: TCP
              containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/local/airflow/dags
              name: airflow-dags
            - mountPath: /usr/local/airflow/airflow.cfg
              name: airflow-configmap
              subPath: airflow.cfg
            - name: airflow-logs
              mountPath: /usr/local/airflow/logs
      volumes:
        - name: airflow-configmap
          configMap:
            name: airflow-configmap
        - name: airflow-dags
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: airflow-dags
        - name: airflow-logs
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: airflow-logs

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: airflow
  namespace: default
  labels:
    env: airflow-test
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: webserver
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30003
  selector:
    env: airflow-test
```

Dag file :

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

def print_world():
    print('world_1')

default_args = {
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2020, 8, 6,9,45,0),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=5),
}

with DAG('tutorial_v01',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval='*/30 * * * *',
         ) as dag:
    print_hello = BashOperator(task_id='print_hello',
                               bash_command='echo "hello"')
    sleep = BashOperator(task_id='sleep',
                         bash_command='sleep 5')
    print_world = PythonOperator(task_id='print_world',
                                 python_callable=print_world)

print_hello >> sleep >> print_world
```

I have already provided 777 to this location `/usr/local/airflow/` in used image, please let me know if anything else required

Comment: is this the right behavior? -> Yes this is correct. Individual task execute as a part of LocalExecutor inside k8s.  I will need more details to answer this. Is your webserver and scheduler pods running fine without any issues ? From the worker pod logs it looks like it cannot access the cfg file. what I want to know is how are you mounting these volumes ? how does the tasks sees the code and how are they writing logs ? Are you using any PV or PVC for this ?

Comment: yes i am using PVC & PV and mounting to host directory like airflow-dags = /home/user/airflow-dags same for logs and my scheduler and webserver working fine.

Comment: ok lets debug this. Once you start the DAG ; can you please go inside to the worker pod in CLI and try to find out who is this running as ? Then see if the file /usr/local/airflow/unittests.cfg is present ? If yes what is the permission and can you do some operations with it ?

Comment: I was trying but I can;t as it gets terminated immediately after start

Comment: ok can you do the same for scheduler pod and check who owns that file for me that is owned by airflow user.

Comment: also can you disable unittest if you dont need it. This is the config. [tests]
unit_test_mode = True

Comment: Also check I think this might be your issue. Looks like how your pod is running as what user. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-6754 . Please let me know if this answers you question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon, you gave me the right direction issue was related to 'run_as_user' prop under the Kubernetes section by default it was 5000 and change that with 0 which is my root user. But still, I have a doubt why it's default value is 5000 is it belong to the airflow user and if we create an airflow user so 5000 id will be assigned or we need to assign?

Comment: Can I add that as an answer and you will select my answer ? Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K8s runs airflow as a docker container.When you are spinning up the container you need to run it as airflow user.

This can be achieved in your dockerfile. You can instruct it to run as a user. Please let me if you want to know more about this.

Also for your above issue. Please refer this.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-6754

Hope this answers your questions. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

following @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon reference links, to make it work..

define `run_as_user = <user uid>` in `airflow.cfg`

or define ENV variable `AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__RUN_AS_USER=<user uid>` in config maps work,

for example,
if your `AIRFLOW_HOME` path has access to `airflow` user than

- identify the user uid by running this command `id -u airflow`

  - now in my case the uid was `1000`
- so now my `airflow.cfg` would have this config `run_as_user = 1000`

ref: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/configurations-ref.html#run-as-user